# jQuery check box

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Just wondering how I can tell if a checkbox is checked or not I tried this

```
if($('#terminalverified').is(':checked')){"yes"}else{"no"});
```

however this did not work, infact what it did was stop my script working all together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( $('#terminalverified').is(':checked') ) {
    alert("yes");
} else {
    alert("no");
}
```

You can also use this:

```
if( $('#terminalverified')[0].checked ) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Idk what you think the strings inside the if statement are going todo.

You could try

```
if($('#terminalverified').is(':checked'))
{
    alert("yes");
}
else
{
    alert("no");
}
```

or

```
alert(($('#terminalverified').is(':checked'))?'yes':'no');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery correctly, but your Javascript syntax is incorrect . Try this:

```
if($('#terminalverified').is(':checked')){
    // Yes it is checked
}else{
    // No it is not checked
};
```

I removed the `)` at the end of your if statement between the `}` and `;` that was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terminalverified" /> Terminal verified

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#terminalverified").click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            alert("yes");
        } else {
            alert("no");
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra closing bracket(`)`) in your code otherwise your code is perfect to check whether `checkbox` is `checked` or not.

```
if($('#terminalverified').is(':checked')){alert("yes")}else{alert("no");};
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var group = document.myForm.check;
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        if (group[i].checked)
            break;
    }
    if (i == group.length) {
        alert("Please check some value");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checksector" id="check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checksector" id="check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checksector" id="check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checksector" id="check">
        <input value="Save" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
```

you can refer `http://www.chennaisunday.com/jscheckbox.html`